# How to test TypeScript + browsersify files with jasmine?

Tags: typescript, gulp, jasmine, browserify

I have some TypeScript files. I used `browsersify` to fuse all these files into a single `bundle.js` (using `tsify` in `gulp`).

So I have some `.ts` in my `/src` and a `bundle.js` in my `/build`.

Now I want to test that. Preferably with `jasmine` and `karma`.

I don't understand how I'm supposed to do that. Jasmine can't used the `.ts` neither the final `build.js` (apparently). 
I do not understand either how things as coverage could work with this technology stack.

Can you give me some tips to run my jasmine tests. What the architecture it is supposed to look like?

Thanks

---- Edit-----

So I've try to include the build.js into my karma

```
files: [
    'build/**/*.js',
    'spec/**/*.spec.js'
]
```

But how to use the Object inside? 
I have a class "Unit" in TypeScript. Browsersify seem to create a structure like that inside a anonymous function

```
var Unit = (function () {
    function Unit() { 
    }
    return Unit;
}());
```

But The scope doesn't allow me to access it from outside (I didn't find how).
So when I do a new `User()` into jasmine I have the following error.

> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Unit

Answer (score 0):

You need to load that bundle.js (assuming it includes your tests) with karma and Karma-jasmine module to run the tests. If you want coverage reports then you should generate source maps for your bundle.js. With source maps you can use remap-istanbul module after running the tests. It will generate coverage data for your typescript files.

Comment: Answered in the post. I don't know how to access to the content of the browsersify anonymous function. What do you mean by "assuming it includes your tests" ?

Comment: I mean you should include test files into bundle.js

Comment: build.js (or bundle.js) is supose to be the final production file. And you don't want to have your tests in a file you will include into you index.html file right? I'm not sure to understand.

Comment: There should be 2 bundles: one for production, one for testing.

Comment: There is a module karma-browserify. Did you try that? The example from a readme at https://github.com/nikku/karma-browserify should work fine. You only need to add typescript preprocessor into it